# SLD not changing style when publishing layer

Tags: qgis, geoserver, sld

I've tried several times creating an SLD in QGIS and then bringing into GeoServer. However, after selecting the style in the Edit Layer-> Publish tab, it remains in the original default color. [image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding a style, not changing the default style on the layer.

In the layer preview there is a button (`...`) that opens a menu that will allow you to change to your new style:

[image]

Or you can make it the default style using the combo box in the layer publish tab.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the "default style" dropdown, what you did there was to add the new style as a secondary option instead.